# How to replace text in a textfield when user enters any character

Tags: android, android-widget, textfield

In my android app I have a text field that says "how much would you like to take".

I want the text to be erased automatically and replaced by what the user inputs when they type in that textfield.

Example: if the user enters one character it automatically deletes "how much would you like to take" from the text field and replaces it with the one character that's been entered.

Comment: replace text after change focus this text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your xml file use

```
android:hint="how much would you like to take"
```

in your `TextView` definition

(Well, it should be something like `"@string/how_much"` and that `how_much` string in strings.xml, but honestly...)

Answer (score 1):

Its called `android:hint` property of a `EditText` you can set it into your xml file.

Something like that.

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="how much would you like to take" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your xml

Use this in below code `android:hint="how much would you like to take"`

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtName" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"     
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
    android:hint="how much would you like to take" 
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    />
```

Hope it helps